# tokens and delims expert help needed

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, token

I have been using batch a lot lately to great ends in my work and also little bits of power shell here and there to great effect.

One thing that always baffles me is the tokens and delims concepts when working through loop etc. I have watched you tube videos and read the classic rob van pages on it. I kind of get it, but when I need to use it's not basic.

I have an example cropped up where if some one was kind enough to explain how you choose the number of tokens and delims it would be really helpful. I need to extrapolate a PC host-name from various columns in a web page. I can copy the text into a text pad and would like to "echo out" into another file just the computer names.

```
24 Nov 2016 09:45 GMT   194.176.105.132 United Kingdom  ID006962.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
24 Nov 2016 09:44 GMT   194.176.105.154 United Kingdom  ID006976.CENTRAL    3.10.5.0    Remove
24 Nov 2016 09:43 GMT   194.176.105.146 United Kingdom  ID007634.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
24 Nov 2016 09:41 GMT   194.176.105.138 United Kingdom  ID006961.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
24 Nov 2016 09:28 GMT   194.176.105.132 United Kingdom  ID007643.CENTRAL    3.10.5.0    Remove
```

The computer names are the **ID0006962** numbers BUT I dont need the trailing  **.CENTRAL**. From this text I just need another text file with the hostnames. I can do all that part, it's just the extrapolating data elements. Sometimes the lists are massive and it would be nice just save into a text file run a for loop against it and spit out a another text file with just the host-names. I think If I can get my head round this a little more I could apply the knowledge to other things I need to do as well. Many thanks for any tips !

sample output (i'd like) in another text file:-

```
ID006967                                                             
ID007566                                                               
ID007567                                                              
ID006976    
ID007643
```

## edit how can I also get the 3.10.6.0 etc next to the host name

```
ID006967     3.10.6.0                                                         
ID007566     3.10.6.0                                                          
ID007567     3.10.6.0                                                         
ID006976     3.10.6.0
ID007643     3.10.6.0
```

I've had a go but got lost here's what I thought...

```
@echo off

> "%~dp0test.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=4,5 delims= " %%J in ("%~dp0rob.txt") do @(
        for /F "tokens=1,3,4,5,6 delims=." %%I in ("%%J") do @echo(%%I
    )
)
```

so my thinking (LOL)...I want the 4,5 tokens (columns 4 and 5) extracting into %%J I want the next loop to echo the additional tokens as well as the host name, so still using '.' as a delimiter in this test with rows 4 and 5 I believe there are now 6 tokens to choose from....but the out put still just show the host name...what don't I get

ID006962(t1).CENTRAL(t2) 3(t3).10(t4).6(t5).0(t6)

Comment: `"Delims= ."` Multiple delimiters are treated as one. Count how many `.` and ` ` there are (I think it's 12) separating tokens. So the 12th letter is L. So `For /f "delims=12 tokens= ." in %%A Do (something) Echo %%A` OR `For /f "tokens= ." in %%A (something) Do %%L`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share! I see two options: 1. `for /F "usebackq tokens=12 delims=. " %%I in ("yourfile.txt") do echo(%%I` (the _space_ in `delims` must be the very last char. in the entire option string), or 2. `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("yourfile.txt") do set "LINE=%%L" & echo(!LINE:~56,8!` (with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled);

Comment: @Noodles, you seem to confuse the `tokens` and the `delims` keywords in the option string; to include a space in `delims` you need to state it as the very last character of the entire option string...

Comment: Please do not change the requirements of your question, particularly when it has already been answered before! Regard that answers might appear incomplete of even wrong then. To solve the new issue: take [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40787752), replace `tokens=4` by `tokens=4,5`, then replace `@echo(%%I` by `@echo(%%I %%K`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions for you.

The first uses the same idea as aschipfl's answer just slightly more refined, remember delims=<kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```bat
@(For /f "UseBackQTokens=4Delims=   " %%A In ("pagedata.txt"
) Do @Echo=%%~nA)>another.txt
```

The second uses the period as a delimiter:

```bat
@(For /f "UseBackQTokens=4Delims=." %%A In ("pagedata.txt"
) Do @For %%B In (%%A.x) Do @If Not "%%~xB"=="" Echo=%%~nB)>another.txt
```

Just change the input filename of pagedata.txt and the ouptput filename of another.txt to suit your purposes.

Comment: …might seem it but try it and you'll find theyre not required

Comment: Hmm. Well I never expected that :)

Comment: second one works a charm, could yield anything from first option, how does second one work, would love to know, thanks!!

Comment: first one works too I missed the tab after delims, how on earth does it do it with so little code !? lol

Comment: all the answers are perfect and do exactly what is wanted, I'm going to tick this one, and any could be ticked, but just because it is a neat little one liner (or 2 depending which one).

Comment: The second one works because `(%%A.x)` will read, _for instance_ `(146 United Kingdom  ID007634.x)` when that runs through the For %%B command looking for a _fake_ extension there's only one found, `.x` that has a _fake_ filename of `ID007634` and outputs it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your data seem to be a <kbd>TAB</kbd>-separated table consisting of six columns. The partial string you want to extract is located in the fourth column. So let us use a `for /F` loop to get the fourth token (note that there is a single <kbd>TAB</kbd> character after `delims=`):

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=4 delims=   " %%J in ("inputfile.txt") do echo(%%J
```

This extracts strings like `ID0006962.CENTRAL`. Now let us split this string by another `for /F` loop:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%I in ("ID0006962.CENTRAL") do echo(%%I
```

Then let us use redirection to output the data to a text file:

```
> "outputfile.txt" echo(ID0006962
```

Finally let us put all those things together to get a working script:

```
> "outputfile.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=4 delims=   " %%J in ("inputfile.txt") do @(
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%I in ("%%J") do @echo(%%I
    )
)
```

Comment: this works also ! thanks, whats the difference between usebackq tokens and just tokens, I'm looking at this and see something, so top line grabs the 4th column out of six, the second one grabs everything before the delim in column 4 which is a . and spits into text?

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help; you will find that `usebackq` controls the meaning of the quotes used to enclose the part within `()`... Yes, you exactly got what the code does...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q40784266.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO CALL :process %%a
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=." %%q IN ("%1") DO IF "%%r" equ "CENTRAL" (
 echo %%q
 GOTO :eof
) ELSE (
 SHIFT
 GOTO process
)

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.
You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q40784266.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Read each line of the input file to `%%a` and call `:process` passing the entire line as parameters.

:process takes the first parameter supplied (`24`) and attempts to parse into tokens using `.` as the delimiter. If the second token (in `%%r`) is not "CENTRAL" then `shift` the parameters and try again.

"Nov","2016","09:45","GMT" each do not have a second token, so shift
"194.176.105.132" has a second token of "176" which doesn't match, so shift
"United","Kingdom" no second token, so shift
"ID006962.CENTRAL" has a second token, it matches "CENTRAL", so print the first,"ID006962" and go to the end, abandoning the remaining parameters "3.10.6.0" and "Remove"

Note that a string such as `Central African Republic` will not fail the testing as the match for `CENTRAL` is case-sensitive and `"Central"` has no second token anyway.

Note that some syntax elements are layout-sensitive. Cut-and-paste is recommended using a text-editor, not a word-processor which may silently "format" the code. Note that `NOTEPAD` tends also to format the code. I use `EDITPLUS`.

Comment: Hey thanks for all these answers will report back when I get a bit of free  time.  Appreciate it  :)

Comment: this also works a charm again I kind of understand but don't know how you choose tokens=1 and 2 delims=. thanks will probably play around to try and understand more

Comment: Tokens & delimiters are easy. Take the string `123.w#q.456`. If `delims` is `.` then there are 3 tokens in the string, `123`, `w#q` & `456`. With `#` there are 2, `123.w` & `q.456`. with `#.` there are 4, `123`,`w`,`q` & `456`. **Tokens** allows you to select the tokens by number. The lowest number selected goes into the specified *metavariable* (loop-control variable), the next selected to the next alphabetically and so on. So with `tokens=2,4delims=#." %%a` then `%%a` gets `w` & `%%b` gets `456`. Any sequence of selected delimiters counts as one and any leading delimiters are ignored.

Comment: Ah okay might experiment with exactly that snippet of text and play around then I'll start getting the hang of it.  Many thanks ;)