# delims spaces and tabs differ from webpage copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, token

I am running for loops on text copied from my works webpage into a text file. I have found copying from Google Chrome, the text content has "delims" of "TAB". If I copy the same info from Internet Explorer the Delims are "SPACES", same with Firefox. This then alters the number of tokens etc. and requires two different sets of code for each type.

So...(example)

Chrome

text copy format

```
2 Dec 2016 12:37 GMT    194.176.105.169 United Kingdom  ID007638.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
2 Dec 2016 12:36 GMT    194.176.105.152 United Kingdom  ID007578.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove
2 Dec 2016 12:34 GMT    194.176.105.166 United Kingdom  ID006715.CENTRAL    3.10.6.0    Remove

for /F "usebackq tokens=5 delims=   " %%J in ("hosts.txt") do @echo(%%J
```

Internet Explorer

text copy format

```
2 Dec 2016 10:16 GMT 194.176.105.132 United Kingdom  ID007643.CENTRAL 3.10.6.0 Remove 
2 Dec 2016 10:16 GMT 194.176.105.133 United Kingdom  ID006967.CENTRAL 3.10.6.0 Remove 
1 Dec 2016 17:59 GMT 194.176.105.139 United Kingdom  ID006972.CENTRAL 3.10.6.0 Remove 
1 Dec 2016 17:55 GMT 194.176.105.132 United Kingdom  ID007574.CENTRAL 3.10.6.0 Remove 

for /F "usebackq tokens=10 delims= " %%J in ("hosts.txt") do @echo(%%J
```

So I could have the user choose from did you copy from chrome or IE, Forefox and then do code xyz, but I would rather the code looked at the text file and somehow saw it was using spaces as delims then run the code for spaces and delims, or if it found tab delims then run the code for that. It's a little project I'm doing for my colleagues and the less they have to do the better. Is this possible? Maybe run a find command on spaces(?) then do X or find the existence of TABS then do y.

Comment: Read the first line of the file into a variable.  Then do a replace on a tab in the variable to remove it and assign it to a new variable.  Compare the first variable to the new one.  If they are equal, then you know there is no tab.

Comment: You know that the `delims=` option default to TAB and SPACE, don't you? Anyway, the main problem seems to be that there are also spaces in the data fields; if the fields are always separated by more than one SPACE, I am thinking of replacing three consecutive SPACEs by two SPACEs several times in a loop (number of iterations depends on maximum number of consecutive SPACESs), then replace two consecutive SPACEs by one TAB, then use TAB as the only delimiter. A completely different approach is to use the character positions, if each line/field is of fixed width (as the examples show)...

Comment: thanks for these, bit out of my league though, any examples would be great ;-)...

Comment: Are you always grabbing the last field of the line?

Comment: well im giving a choice of just version number of software which is the 3.10.6.0 bit, the hostname parts which is (ID007643.CENTRAL minus .central) ID007643 or both. So 3 choices will open a text file with the appropriate data. 1 will open version number only, another will open hostame of PC only the last one will open them both together in a text file.

Comment: I'll refer you back to your almost-identical question from earlier, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784266/tokens-and-delims-expert-help-needed Since you don't tell us explicitly what data you want by say - giving an example, it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this method solve your problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "hostname=!version!"
      set "version=!last!"
      set "last=%%b"
   )
   echo Hostname: !hostname!,  version: !version!
)
```

This method take the last-but-one and "last-but-two" (is correctly written?) fields of the line separated by spaces or TABs.

**EDIT**: *New solution as reply to comments*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the fields
set "field[1]=Version"
set "field[2]=Hostname"
set "field[4]=IPaddress"

rem Show the options
:start
cls
set "choice="
for /L %%i in (1,1,7) do (
   set "option=%%i. Extract"
   for %%j in (1,2,4) do (
      set /A "j=%%i&%%j"
      if !j! neq 0 set "option=!option! !field[%%j]! and"
   )
   echo !option:~0,-4!
   set "choice=!choice!%%i"
)
echo X. Exit
echo/

rem Get the option and assemble the output format
choice /C %choice%X /N /M "Select option: "
set "choice=%errorlevel%"
if %choice% gtr 7 goto :EOF
set "output="
set "file="
for %%j in (1,2,4) do (
   set /A "j=choice&%%j"
   if !j! neq 0 (
      set "output=!output!^!!field[%%j]!^!  "
      set "file=!file!!field[%%j]! "
   )
)

rem Read input file and generate output file
(for /F "usebackq tokens=6*" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
   set "IPaddress=%%a"
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for %%d in ("!version!") do set "hostname=%%~Nd"
      set "version=!last!"
      set "last=%%c"
   )
   echo %output%
)) > "%file:~0,-1%.txt"
start "" "%file:~0,-1%.txt"
goto start
```

Comment: Almost! In my batch the user can choose to show the Hostname only in a text file which would be ID007638 (separated from ID007638.CENTRAL and no commas etc.). Option 2 to pop up a list of version types so a list of 3.10.6.0 or 3.9.9.4 which ever. And finally both together just hostname & software version ID007638  3.10.6.0. Basicall the same code repeated but tweaked to just show slight variations.

Comment: this actually will work, I can edit the echo into a text with what I want then use the code on the new text file which has both colomns. Thanks. Will post when I finish it.

Comment: thanks for this, I managed to get something working using this with a slight tweak. :_)

Comment: How can I make it so the IP address come though aswell, is that possible?? Thanks!

Comment: When you state a problem, you must clearly describe the important points. I am sure you know that the `tokens` option works on individual items, so the important point here is to know _how many items_ are in each position. This FOR command read the posted data and show the IP address, the Hostname and the Version: `for /F "tokens=6,9,10" %%a in (hosts.txt) do echo %%a %%~Nb %%c`. However, I **ASSUMED** that the `United Kingdom` field may have more or less words although you **NOT** described this _important point_, so I opted to get the "last-but-one" and "last-but-two" fields in my solution.

Comment: An entirely different problem is when you change the specifications of a problem as you go along. For example: _"the hostname parts which is ID007643.CENTRAL minus .central"_ and _"So 3 choices will open a text file with the appropriate data..."_ specifications appear **in a comment!** You said that my solution _"Almost work"_ because it does not fullfill _the comments_? **`:(`** You should pay attention to Magoo's comment and to aschipfl's comment in the linked question: _"Please do not change the requirements of your question, particularly when it has already been answered before!"_.

Comment: Anyway, I decided to play your own game, so I wrote a new solution that is based on your question (and comments), but that also include my own _additional specifications_; see the edit in my answer. Please, do not post any questions about this new code here, I will not answer they. IMHO you should learn to post complete questions and not change the specifications after that, but post a new question instead... **`:/`**

Comment: This is excellent answer and is working perfectly on tests.  Apologies for the conduct of my questions which seems to offset everybody.  Before posting I shall think of all eventualities so I don't split over multiple entries. I only did it in case my comment didn't get seen.  Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as in what ever format (copied with space or tab delims) you throw at it it creates a spaced delimited text file with all the extracted information to then further interrogate..

copy and paste from any browser into a hosts.txt then output the contents into another text file....(hosts2.txt)

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "hostname=!version!"
      set "version=!last!"
      set "last=%%b"
    )
    echo !hostname! !version!>>"hosts2.txt"
)
```

then I'm using the below to show either "just the hostname in a txt file", "just the version number in a txt file" or both "version and hostname in a txt file"

```
:start
CLS
echo.
echo                    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo                    ::        1. Extract Hostnames                 ::
Echo                    ::        2. Extract Version                   ::
echo                    ::        3. Extract Hostnames and Version     ::
echo                    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo.
SET /P "Input= "
if '%Input%'=='1' (goto run1)
if '%Input%'=='2' (goto run2)
if '%Input%'=='3' (goto run3)

:run1
> "hostnames.txt" (
        for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=." %%J in ("hosts2.txt") do @echo(%%J
)
start "" "hostnames.txt"
goto start

:run2
> "version.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %%J in ("hosts2.txt") do @echo(%%J
)
start "" "version.txt"
goto start


:run3
> "hostnver.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims= " %%J in ("hosts2.txt") do @(
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%I in ("%%J") do @echo(%%I %%K
    )
)
start "" "hostnver.txt"
goto start
```